# how to make the running function like reading the text to stop reading it by using other function to stop it?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tkinter-button

I have made a function to read the text using pyttsx3 and i have created a stop  button using tkinter so when i click it , it will call another function which will stop the reading function to stop reading the text
i am not able to do it , i used sys.exit() and it did not work

```
def stop_voice():
    sys.exit(talk)
```

```
def talk():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
    engine.say(details.get(1.0, END))
    engine.runAndWait()
```

```
Button(infoframe,text='Stop',command=stop_voice,bg='red',width=15,activebackground='blue').place(x=200,y=660)
#used threading so both text and talk can run
        t1=Thread(target=talk)

        t1.start()
```

Comment: sys.exit() takes an arguenment? Myb try without it.

Comment: i did but it did not work either

Comment: Maybe kill the thread - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/

Comment: Try using `engine.stop()`.